# Using Bootstrap with Parse

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, parsing

I've just started web dev and I'm trying to use Parse to host my website.

I started off with just working on an index.html file with bootstrap stuff in my working directory. Let's call this directory MySite.

```
MySite
   |___css/
   |___fonts/
   |___js/
   |___index.html
```

I then decided to host the site using Parse. So I created a Parse Code Cloud inside MySite:

```
MySite/
   |___css/
   |___fonts/
   |___js/
   |___index.html
   |___MySiteCloud/
            |___cloud/
            |___config/
            |___public/
                    |___index.html
```

I've symlinked the index.html from inside public/ to the index.html in MySite.

Now, when I try to check out my webpage mysite.parseapp.com, none of the bootstrap styling stuff is in there.

Where do I need to save the bootstrap files to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with some experimenting.

You have to put the Bootstrap files in the public folder.

If anybody has a better answer to this, please let me know.